# Fields added to Django's AbstractUser aren't showing up in the migration

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a custom `User` model based on `AbstractUser`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    certs_only: models.BooleanField()
```

When I run `manage.py makemigrations`, the migrations are created, but the `certs_only` field isn't there. All other fields from `AbstractUser` are there, eg `password`, `last_login`, etc. I see this migration in 0001_initial.py. This field also doesn't show up in the admin site, since it doesn't actually exist.

I've tried `./manage.py makemigrations common`, as some suggested ('common' is my app name), but this made no difference. I've also tried adding fields of different types, but this seems to happen regardless.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Dis you mean `certs_only = models.BooleanField()` ?

Comment: Oh man I'm kicking myself right now. Yes, that was my mistake.

Comment: I'll accept that answer if you submit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean

```
certs_only = models.BooleanField()
```